# how do I make my radio button become clear again when I pick a different value?

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm posting the link where I am having the problem.  I'm having issues with the radio buttons.

I have three images and I'm suppose to be able to click on a radio button and the image changes.  That part works great.  But when I go for another button, the last one I clicked on stays checked.  How do I make it uncheck?  I only want what is selected to be checked. ty!!!!!

http://www-desi.iro.umontreal.ca/~valiquki/tp3Kim/TP3KimValiquette.html

Answer (score 1):

The radio buttons have to have the same "name" attribute to be a part of the same group.

Comment: oh my gosh oh my gosh!  ty!!!!!  I can now almost turn in my assignment and go home!  =D ^^

Comment: I wish I could vote for peoples answers but my reputation is not high enough yet ^^

Comment: You can click the "checkmark" icon though to designate the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @Kim you can "accept" an answer by clicking the hollow green check mark next to that answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all of the radio buttons are in the same group.  See [this](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm) for how to do so.

Basically, use the `name` attribute to assign a group name. That way they will be part of a group and the browser will handle selection/deselection.  Name is not the name of the radio button, but the name of the group.

You could use 'side-dishes' if you like for all of them.